Instagram Graph APIの利用に必要な、3つ目のアクセストークンが取得できない
Instagram Graph APIを利用して、どのようなデータが取得できるか検証を行いたいのですが、その際に必要な3つ目のアクセストークンが取得できません。2つ目のトークンまでは取得できるものの、3つ目のトークンを取得しようとすると、空のjsonが返ってくる状況です。
既に試したことは以下です。もし何か間違っている部分があったり、正しいやり方をご存知の方がいらっしゃったら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

Instagramのプロアカウントへの切り替え
Facebookページの作成
FacebookページとInstagramプロアカウントの連携
Meta For DevelopersでFacebookアプリの作成
グラフAPIエクスプローラで１つ目のアクセストークンを取得
1つ目のアクセストークンを使って、以下のURLから2つ目のアクセストークンを取得

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id=「アプリID」&client_secret=「app secret」&fb_exchange_token=「1つ目のアクセストークン」


以下のURLからidを取得

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me?access_token=「2つ目のアクセストークン」


以下のURLから3つ目のアクセストークンを取得しようとすると、dataと書かれた空のjsonが返ってくるだけ

https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/「id」/accounts?access_token=「2つ目のアクセストークン」




実際にやるにあたっては、こちらの記事などを参考にしてみました。もし、3つ目のアクセストークン取得方法について、正しいやり方をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願いいたします。

詳しくないので直接の回答はできませんが、まずは 公式のスタートガイド を参照するべきです。「どのようなデータが取得できるのか」も ドキュメント を参照しましょう。
